# Has anyone had any success using twitters typeahead.js within visualforce pages?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to get [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) to work within salesforce visualforce pages.

I have a basic vf page from [this](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) example, but it does not respopnd, I suspect there may be some "unknown" workaround needed? Does anyone know?

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0"  standardStylesheets="false">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>   


<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA"/>
</div>

<script>
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substrRegex;

        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
          if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
            // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
            // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
            matches.push({ value: str });
          }
        });

        cb(matches);
      };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
      'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
      'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
      'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
      'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
      'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
      'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
      'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
      'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'states',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from Salesforce Foundation Team.

It works very fine for me.

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/visualforce-typeahead

And your script has a very minor minor bug, and change **`http`** to **`https`**, the script works quit fine.

[image]

Change

`<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, yes this looks like a useful approach, much more complex than I need. Would love to know if anyone can figure where I am going wrong with the simple example above? it works as plain html, but fails when made force.com

Comment: Answer is updated

Answer (score 1):

If the https doesn't solve your problem, be sure to try the following "standard things to do for VF: "

Set $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
Then use $j everywhere you currently have $.

SF uses $ as in {!$Stuff} so sometimes jquery stuff needs no-conflicting.

I do have typeahead running...is there some CSS that it needs?

Also, try wrapping it in a ready function--you don't want it executing before jquery has come back.

Comment: The $ in Visualforce merge syntax referencing global variables isn't what conflicts with the jQuery library's mapping of the `$` character to `jQuery`. The conflict occurs because Salesforce uses the Prototype JavaScript framework in its pages and Prototype also uses the `$` character for its own shortcut reference. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/ So, having both Prototype and jQuery in the same page will usually cause an undesired overwriting of the $ variable from Prototype to jQuery and break all of the other dependencies that Salesforce has to the Prototype library in its pages.

Comment: Thanks,,, yes good point. I have also now added the the no conflict.